# How to Implement data change approval using c# .net

Tags: asp.net, database

I am writing an application that requires any change/update done by a user has to be approved by a super user before being inserted in the actual table(s). Any approach/best practice (apart from .net work flows) ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is primarily opinion based, however one approach that I recently used in my Employees Payroll System was;

Upon late comings, an employee could file a "Late Approval Request" which would only be applicable once approved by the team lead and then department lead (2 step approvals).

The table design:

[image]

[image]

-1 defines "Rejection"

0 defines "Status Pending"

1 defines "Approved"

Comment: the best answer for your case @karufere you can use a post_id for your post and the get the user id who has changed the content. then by default save -1(not approved) when admin approves it will be 1(approved) and query and show all approved posts to your front end where you wanna output your practice. well done #user